# String split and duplicate row in R?

Tags: r, split, duplicates, rbind

I have a database as follow:

```
col1 <-c("X1",";X2","X3;X4;X5","X6;X7")
[1] "X1"       ";X2"      "X3;X4;X5" "X6;X7" 
col2 = col3 = col4 <- c("5","8","4","1")
[1] "5" "8" "1" "4"
dat <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4)
 dat
      col1 col2 col3 col4
1       X1    5    5    5
2      ;X2    8    8    8
3 X3;X4;X5    4    4    4
4    X6;X7    1    1    1
```

I want to remove semi colon in column 1 and if column 1 which contains over one X, it will duplicate new rows.
Moreover, column 2 and 3 will duplicate values, column 4 will replace by value 0. I expect it will be:

```
dat
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1   X1    5    5    5
2   X2    8    8    8
3   X3    4    4    4
4   X4    4    4    0
5   X5    4    4    0
6   X6    1    1    1
7   X7    1    1    0
```

Comment: Please don't quote the numeric values.  It will be read as `factor/character` columns depending upon whether you specify the `stringsAsFactors=TRUE/FALSE`

Answer (score 6):

This splits `col1` by semicolon and uses tidyr's `unnest` to explode single rows into multiple rows as needed.   Next it uses `filter` to remove unwanted rows that were generated by leading (or trailing or multiple) semicolons.  tidyr puts `col1` last so we rearrange using `select`. Alternately, if the column order does not matter just omit the `select`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

   dat %>%
       mutate(col1 = strsplit(as.character(col1), ";")) %>%
       unnest(col1) %>%
       filter(col1 != "") %>%
       select(col1, col2:col4)
```

giving:

```
Source: local data frame [7 x 4]

       col1   col2   col3   col4
      (chr) (fctr) (fctr) (fctr)
    1    X1      5      5      5
    2    X2      8      8      8
    3    X3      4      4      4
    4    X4      4      4      4
    5    X5      4      4      4
    6    X6      1      1      1
    7    X7      1      1      1
```

Comment: You could specify `fixed = TRUE` to speed it up a bit

Comment: Thanks Sir...
Just a update now, unnest need a cols parameter as:
unnest(cols = col1)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(dat, "col1", ";", "long")[col1!=""][duplicated(col4), col4 := as.numeric(0)][]
#    col1 col2 col3 col4
#1:   X1    5    5    5
#2:   X2    8    8    8
#3:   X3    4    4    4
#4:   X4    4    4    0
#5:   X5    4    4    0
#6:   X6    1    1    1
#7:   X7    1    1    0
```

#### data

```
col2 = col3 = col4 <- c(5,8,4,1)
 dat <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4)
```

Comment: please help me, in case col1 contains only the letter like "" or NA, it will delete that row. How could I keep that rows? Thank you.

Comment: @MinhPhúcHuỳnh  Could you update your post with the new case and the expected output.